# How to get previous min and max values in new columns for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In each new row of dataframe, I need to keep track of min and max values for a previous group of records.

1. Create dataframe with input data:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['timestamp','groupid','value']
data =      [['2022-10-14 11:47:38',1000,200],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:39',1000,210],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:40',1000,220],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:41',1000,230],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:42',1001,240],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:43',1001,250],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:44',1002,260],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:45',1002,270]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
print(df)
```

2. Calculate min and max values for each group:

```
df['min'] = df.groupby('groupid')['value'].transform('min')
df['max'] = df.groupby('groupid')['value'].transform('max')
```

3. Create new columns in dataframe:

```
df['pmin'] = 0
df['pmax'] = 0
df['ppmin'] = 0
df['ppmax'] = 0
df['ppmin'] = df.groupby('groupid')['pmin'].transform('first').shift(1)
df['ppmax'] = df.groupby('groupid')['pmax'].transform('first').shift(1)
df['pmin'] = df.groupby('groupid')['min'].transform('first').shift(1)
df['pmax'] = df.groupby('groupid')['max'].transform('first').shift(1)
print(df)
```

The code in step 3 fails to return expected result as shown below:

```
columns2 = ['timestamp','groupid','value','min','max','pmin','pmax','ppmin','ppmax']
data2 =      [['2022-10-14 11:47:38',1000,200,200,230,0,0,0,0],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:39',1000,210,200,230,0,0,0,0],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:40',1000,220,200,230,0,0,0,0],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:41',1000,230,200,230,0,0,0,0],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:42',1001,240,240,250,200,230,0,0],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:43',1001,250,240,250,200,230,0,0],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:44',1002,260,260,270,240,250,200,230],
            ['2022-10-14 11:47:45',1002,270,260,270,240,250,200,230]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=columns2)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest solution:

```py
df["tmp"] = (df["groupid"] != df["groupid"].shift()).cumsum()
grps = df.groupby("groupid")["value"]

df["min"] = grps.transform("min")
df["max"] = grps.transform("max")

mapper = df.drop_duplicates("tmp").set_index("tmp")[["min", "max"]]

tmp1 = df["tmp"] - 1
tmp2 = df["tmp"] - 2

df["pmin"] = tmp1.map(mapper["min"])
df["pmax"] = tmp1.map(mapper["max"])

df["ppmin"] = tmp2.map(mapper["min"])
df["ppmax"] = tmp2.map(mapper["max"])

print(df.fillna(0).drop(columns="tmp"))
```

Prints:

```
             timestamp  groupid  value  min  max   pmin   pmax  ppmin  ppmax
0  2022-10-14 11:47:38     1000    200  200  230    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1  2022-10-14 11:47:39     1000    210  200  230    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2  2022-10-14 11:47:40     1000    220  200  230    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
3  2022-10-14 11:47:41     1000    230  200  230    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
4  2022-10-14 11:47:42     1001    240  240  250  200.0  230.0    0.0    0.0
5  2022-10-14 11:47:43     1001    250  240  250  200.0  230.0    0.0    0.0
6  2022-10-14 11:47:44     1002    260  260  270  240.0  250.0  200.0  230.0
7  2022-10-14 11:47:45     1002    270  260  270  240.0  250.0  200.0  230.0
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to helping me out ! I am now able to move forward. And, it is just as much important to appreciate this voluntary help. On the other hand, it is taking 116ms to run on my data that has about 12K rows and 60 columns. Since time is very critical for the app, I would appreciate if anyone has more leads or a solution for more efficient performance. Thank you once again.

Comment: @plain I've minor edited the code, should be slightly faster now. Try the answer by sammywemmy, looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Build the dataframe of aggregation and shifts, and merge to get the final output:

```py
grp = df.groupby('groupid')['value']
min_max = grp.agg(['min', 'max'])
pmin_max = min_max.add_prefix('p').shift(fill_value = 0)
ppmin_max = min_max.add_prefix('p').shift(2, fill_value = 0).add_prefix('p')
other = pd.concat([min_max, pmin_max, ppmin_max], axis = 1)
df.merge(other, on = 'groupid')

             timestamp  groupid  value  min  max  pmin  pmax  ppmin  ppmax
0  2022-10-14 11:47:38     1000    200  200  230     0     0      0      0
1  2022-10-14 11:47:39     1000    210  200  230     0     0      0      0
2  2022-10-14 11:47:40     1000    220  200  230     0     0      0      0
3  2022-10-14 11:47:41     1000    230  200  230     0     0      0      0
4  2022-10-14 11:47:42     1001    240  240  250   200   230      0      0
5  2022-10-14 11:47:43     1001    250  240  250   200   230      0      0
6  2022-10-14 11:47:44     1002    260  260  270   240   250    200    230
7  2022-10-14 11:47:45     1002    270  260  270   240   250    200    230
```